# In unix console, pasted a line and I want to redirect to z.txt .Is it possible? and when I did again it should not append

Tags: file, unix, redirect, input, console

I want to give a line in a console to create a file directly from console.

e.g.:

```
unix$ this is vamsi > z.txt
```

But it doesn't work. Is  it possible? And when I try to give new line

e.g.:

```
unix$ i like you > z.txt
```

It should not append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add quotes:

```
echo "this is vamsi" > z.txt
```

The above creates a file `z.txt` with the content "this is vamsi". Repeating such a command will *overwrite* the file content (replace it), not append. You *could* append content by using the `>>` operator. Take care to use correct line breaks though.